# How to create "filters" for class' methods?

Tags: c#

With ASP.NET I have created a few filters extending both `ExceptionFilterAttribute` and `ActionFilterAttribute`. With `ActionFilterAttribute` I can execute actions before or after the method's execution. I'd like to mimic that behavior on my class. I have a base class called `BaseService` and whenever a method from this class is invoked I'd like to check if it contains an attribute and if it does execute that. For instance, on my derived classes I have methods like:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    LoggedUser.RequireAnyRole<RoleX, RoleY>("DoSomething");

    // code here
}

public void DoSomething2()
{
    LoggedUser.RequireRole<RoleX>("DoSomething2");

    // code here
}
```

Instead of writing `LoggedUser.RequireRole...` I'd like it to be an attribute. That way I'd just add an attribute on top of `DoSomething2`: `[RequireRole(Roles.X)]`.

Is this possible? If so, what is the best approach? I was reading something related to callmember, but I'm not sure that's the way to do it. I checked https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack for its implementation but I think I didn't know how to search for it since I didn't find anything...

Comment: The amount of code needed for such a feature is too big (or too expensive in terms of performance for using reflection). Why do you think an attribute is simpler than a code line inside your method?

Comment: @FedericoDipuma hey, thanks for your input. I didn't think it was simpler in terms of performance, but it is simpler in terms of usage. It's way easier (and IMO, cleaner) to write an attribute instead of writing that line of code every time. But again, I wasn't thinking about performance. Would you say it crosses the cost/benefit threshold? Thanks.

Comment: @eestein I think [Custom Attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40777791/custom-authorization-filter-in-asp-net-mvc-5) is one of ways to achieve your use case.

Comment: @SivaGopal thanks, but how would I "tell" the class what to do with that attribute? i.e: execute its code before executing the method's code. Thanks.

Comment: @eestein [This Attributes tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(v=vs.71).aspx) may help you.

Comment: @SivaGopal thanks again, Siva. I'm aware of that. The thing is, with the attribute defined that way (standard), I can't access the class's instance objects like `LoggedUser`. That's why I'm asking here how to implement that, it's not a simple attribute class. when the attribute is being executed I need to have access to the class' instance. Like with the `ActionFilter` you have access to the context. Thanks.