# User.IsInRole("x") always null in one ActionResult and works in another. Why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

User is always null in the second ActionResult and works correctly in the first. Both are in the same Controller.
Only difference I can think of is that the first `Page` is serving a dynamic page while the second `SpecialReports` are static files in a folder.

Why is this? Is there a fix?

```
public ActionResult Page(string it)
    {
        MVpage page = new MVpage(it);

          //some code

        if (!page.Content.Published && !User.IsInRole("Admin")) //works fine!
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 307; 
            return View("Woops");
        }

        return View(page);
    }
public ActionResult SpecialReports(string name)
    {

        if (!name.Contains("pdf") && !User.IsInRole("Admin"))//Doesn't work! User==null :(
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 307;
            return View("Woops");
        }
        return new FilePathResult("~/x/" + name, y);
    }
```

Comment: User is usually set with Authorize and/or Authentication filters. Did you set them properly?

Comment: @EmrahSüngü I didn't set a filter but the first ActionResult works fine without it. Can you please link to an example?

Comment: Please have a look at this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40777791/custom-authorization-filter-in-asp-net-mvc-5

PS: I also think that in your `Page(string it)` method `User` is `null`. Can you debug and confirm it?

Comment: @EmrahSüngü Thanks for the link (and your help). User is not null, see screenshot https://screenshots.firefox.com/CpUsiuJ3dytvIoKU/null

Comment: Which authentication type are you using? Cookies? OpenID? OAuth2? Something else?

Comment: @Housy I am using the WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity class to handle this. I'm not sure what type its based on.