# Complex role authorization Asp.net core MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have written following code to handle authorization. Providing access or no access can be achieve with authorize attribute. My question is : Is there a standard way of handling partial access where some users have access to everything and some other to few resources based on role as shown in the **if statement** below? 
Writing **if else block** such as shown below everywhere doesn't seem right to me? Please suggest if there are any better way of doing it.

```
 [Authorize(Roles ="admin,superadmin")]
   public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
   {
           if (User.IsInRole("superadmin"))
            {
                //get all groups
            }
            else
            {
              //get only groups that the user belong to
            }

   }
```

Updated (solution) based on this discussion: I have added following code to handle my scenario. Any comments or suggestions welcome.

```
public class SuperAdminUsersRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
    {
        public SuperAdminUsersRequirement(params string[] roles)
        {
            AllowedRoles = roles;
        }
        public string[] AllowedRoles { get; set; }
    }
    public class SuperAdminAuthorizationHander : AuthorizationHandler<SuperAdminUsersRequirement>
    {
        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, SuperAdminUsersRequirement requirement)
        {
            if(UserIsAllowed(context, requirement))
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }
            else
            {
                context.Fail();
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private bool  UserIsAllowed(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, SuperAdminUsersRequirement requirement)
        {
            if (context.User.Claims != null)
            {
                var claims = from userClaims in context.User.Claims
                             where userClaims.Type == ClaimTypes.Role
                             select userClaims.Value;
                if (requirement.AllowedRoles.Intersect(claims, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).Any())
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

startup.cs : can be configure to add more role having all access

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("HasAllAccess", policy =>
                    policy.Requirements.Add(new SuperAdminUsersRequirement(AdminRole.SUPER_ADMIN.ToString()
                        )));
            });
```

controller.cs

```
var authorizationResult = await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, "HasAllAccess");

 if(authorizationResult.Succeeded)
            {
 //fetch everything
    }
else
{
  // fetch partial data
}
```

Comment: Write your own attribute based on System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: @joe Audette . But still we have to use all those conditional checking with the example you provided right?

Comment: You can refer this for custome authorization attribute https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40777791/custom-authorization-filter-in-asp-net-mvc-5

Comment: You're looking for resource-based authorization: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x. Don't listen to the custom authorize attribute nonsense. That's for ASP.NET MVC, not Core.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Could you please give an idea on how the above scenario be done using resource-based-authorization? May be some pseudo code

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of code samples available for [Resource-based authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-2.2) :

https://andrewlock.net/resource-specific-authorisation-in-asp-net-core/

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/architecture-center/blob/master/docs/multitenant-identity/authorize.md

For your requirement , modify `HandleRequirementAsync`function in `AuthorizationHandler` which inheriting from `AuthorizationHandler<YourRequirement, ResourceName>`, you should check whether user has correct role/roles based on your requirement :

```
if (context.User.HasClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, Roles.SurveyAdmin))
{
    context.Succeed(requirement);
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

Or :

```
if (context.User.IsInRole("super_user"))
{
    context.Succeed(requirement);
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

Comment: could you please provide some help on this questions : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57078294/iauthorizationservice-and-layered-architecture-in-asp-net-core?noredirect=1&lq=1